# Test command line arguments

Tags: go

Ho do you test command line arguments?

I can do this:

```
func TestMainFunc(t *testing.T) {
    _, filename, _, _ := runtime.Caller(0)
    dir := filepath.Dir(filename)

    os.Args[1] = dir
    main()
}
```

But then I override "test.v" in an argument list of:

```
os.Args[0]={string} "/private/var/folder/.../___appname.go"
os.Args[1]={string} "test.v"
os.Args[2]={string} "-test.panicontext0"
os.Args[3]={string} "^QTestMainFunc\E$"
```

I have no idea what these arguments are doing, but I suspect it is not good to override any of them - so how can you test arguments?

Comment: `main()` should be as minimal as possible; any logic you need to test should be a function called by `main`, that takes anything it needs as parameters - so, instead of reading params from `os.Args`, it should read params from a `[]string` parameter to the function, which `main` would pass `os.Args` to, but your test would pass test data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To expand upon Adrian's comment a bit, I would separate flag parsing from configuration entirely. Here's an example:

```
type Config struct {
    verbose  bool
    greeting string
    level    int
}

func parseArgs(progname string, args []string) (config *Config, output string, err error) {
    flags := flag.NewFlagSet(progname, flag.ContinueOnError)
    var buf bytes.Buffer
    flags.SetOutput(&buf)

    var conf Config
    flags.BoolVar(&conf.verbose, "verbose", false, "set verbosity")
    flags.StringVar(&conf.greeting, "greeting", "", "set greeting")
    flags.IntVar(&conf.level, "level", 0, "set level")

    err = flags.Parse(args)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, buf.String(), err
    }
    return &conf, "", nil
}
```

The `parseArgs` function parses your program's configuration from command-line arguments, and is easily testable *in isolation* from the rest of the program.

So the flow in `main` would be:

```
func main() {
  conf, output, err := parseArgs(os.Args[0], os.Args[1:])
  if err != nil {
    // ...
  }
  realMain(conf)
}
```

And now you can test `parseArgs` and `realMain` completely separately in unit tests.
This also opens up the possibility to have multiple sources for configuration: e.g. you could also read it from env vars or config files, or command-line. Multiple readers could populate a `Config` struct, and all would be testable in isolation.